# Explanation of Element Theory?

Tags: phonology

Can anyone please provide a simple explanation of element theory for someone who knows nothing  about it? If you could help me answer the following:

What is element theory? What are elements?
How does it differ from feature theory and other forms of representation?
How are elements involved in phonological processes such as harmony?

I have been having trouble understanding some resources and would really appreciate if someone could help shed light on this topic.

Comment: Please give us some context, or a reference. "Element theory" means nothing to me.

Comment: It's a well-known theory of phonology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Element Theory is an autosegmental theory of phonology coming from Government Phonology promulgated by Kaye, Harris, Lindsey, Rennison and others. The essential difference between a feature and an element is that a feature is not pronounceable on its own, but an element is. For example, [+low] cannot be pronounced by itself, but the element that sort of corresponds to [+low], namely A, can be – it's [a]. The three vowel elements, as far as I know, are A ("nonhigh"), I ("front"), U ("round"), and three of the consonant elements are H ("aspirated, voiceless"), N ("nasal, voiced", ʔ ("occluded"), and when not combined with anything, they are [a i u h n ʔ]. The combination of I and A is pronounced [e], [U] and [I] is [y]. Similarly, [p] is [U.ʔ.H]. There may also be an element "@" i.e. [ə], formerly called "the cold vowel", which is something like a neutrino (it doesn't interact with other things).

The theory also includes a concept of "headedness" (usually indicated by underlining but notated here with italics), so that *A*.I is [ɛ] and [A.*I*] is [e] (essentially, the head properties are stronger than the no-head properties). I belive that the difference between [ts], [tʃ] and [tç] is that [ts] is [*A*.I.ʔ.H], [tʃ] is [A.I.ʔ.H] and [tç] is [A.*I*.ʔ.H].

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting. Reminds me of reconstructing PIE vowels, or Skt _guṇa_ and _vŗddhi_.

Comment: Surely you meant Element Theory, not Elements?